# Auto generated gallery with PHP

Tags: php, image, function, math, count

I have a minimum of 2 images and a maximum of 8 images per page. Depending on the number of images I have it's going to generate a gallery differently.

**Here is a diagram of how it should work**

```
8 - 4x4
7 - 4x3
6 - 3x3
5 - 3x2
4 - 4
3 - 3
2 - 2
```

The first column has the number of total images. The following numbers are images in a row.

**Example**

If I have 7 images, it should return an array like:

```
array(4,3)
```

The final result is that I will loop out 4 images on the first row and then 3 larger images on the second row.

**If statements**

I could do this with if statements but I guess there could be a way to calculate this?

**Solution for everyone**

If this is going to be useful for more people then it would need a function like this:

```
function getGalleryRows($count, $row_limit) {
}
```

where `$count` is the number of images and `$row_limit` is the maximum number of images there can be in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I get you right but is this what you want?

```
function getGalleryRows($count, $row_limit) {
  $arr = array();
  while ($count > 0){
    array_push($arr, (($count > $row_limit) ? $row_limit : $count));
    $count -= $row_limit;
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

Examples

```
echo json_encode(getGalleryRows(7,2)); // returns [2,2,2,1]
echo json_encode(getGalleryRows(7,4)); // returns [4,3]
```

Comment: Oh my! You figured it out! So short and sweet. I really tried to break it somehow but I could not. Good job!